# Wiring multiple L5-30 circuits together

Tags: wiring

Theoretically speaking, if I take the hot, neutral and ground wires from two separate L5-30 receptacles and combine them at a terminal block to power a single load, are there any safety implications of doing this?

Comment: There are several. How about zooming out a bit and asking us to help with what you're trying to do, rather than your dangerous 'solution'?

Comment: Are you trying to get 30a 240v or 60a 120v, and for what purpose?

Comment: @manassehkatz-Moving2Codidact Trying to get 60A, 120V. It is for a rack of lights. I could always split the lights up into two separate circuits so no big deal. I was just curious what the issues were with what I was originally proposing to do which I assumed was a bad idea but just wanted some external input.

Comment: @flamezdude if you combine the hot of one circuit with the hot of a second circuit in a 120/240v system, (ie. with a double 30A circuit breaker) you will not end up with 120v @ 60A. You will instead have a short circuit at 240V. Aka. When you flip that breaker, there may be a serious arc flash, a loud bang, and potentially a fire.

Run two separate 120V 30A circuits to achieve your goal.

Comment: Depending on the type/use of the lights, you may find it is far better to go with 3 x 120V x 20A rather than 2 x 120V x 30A. Why? Because 20A wiring, switches, etc. are much cheaper and easier to work with. But that is a **LOT** of light. Assuming continuous usage, 48A @ 120V (because 80% derate) = 5,760W of lighting. That would be a lot for incandescent. With LED it is **HUMONGOUS**. Which means either you are (cough, cough) growing lots of stuff indoors or lighting up a personal football stadium. Either way, seriously look at your types of lighting - if you aren't using LEDs, you should be.

Comment: What is the home improvement connection here? Between this and your other question, it seems like there isn’t one.

Comment: I really wish people would write an answer saying "The answer to your question is HELL NO", rather than misusing the upvote/downvote system to say that.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Based on comments, this is for a 2 x 30A x 120V of lighting.

First the primary safety issue. There are two ways to combine two hots in the US 120V/240V system. Each has a big complication here.

- Same leg

If the two hots are on the same leg then you are putting 60A on a single set of wires from the point that the two circuits are joined. That means you would need 6 AWG copper or 4 AWG aluminum instead of 10 AWG (copper or aluminum) wires from the junction to the string of lights.

But this is called *paralleling*. That means you are effectively splitting the current across two sets of wires. You can't do that because you can't control how much current is on each wire. Which in theory shouldn't be a problem because if one of the hot wires breaks then the other hot wire will carry the full load (48A) and trip the breaker. Fine? **No!** Because if instead of a hot wire breaking, a *neutral* wire breaks, the other neutral will carry all 48A and burn up, because in the standard US system neutrals do not have overcurrent protection.

- Different legs

If you have one circuit on one leg and the other circuit on the other leg then they are each 120V to neutral but 240V to each other. That actually solves the neutral problem, because neutral carries only the difference between the hots. However, to do this properly you have to either use 240V lights (which are actually readily available - many large LED fixtures are designed for 120V - 277V) or be very, very careful that you don't end up shorting through at 240V.

In addition there is the issue, with either configuration, of balancing power between wires in each cable/circuit. In the same leg method it *should* be naturally balanced (or close) until something breaks. In the different legs method if you are actually running the lights at 240V then you will have a total imbalance on both circuits because each will have a single hot with nothing on the neutral. **Not good at all.**

##### Solutions

There are a couple of solutions. First of all, this is a **LOT** of light. If you have not already made the move from incandescent to LEDs, now is the time - the energy savings on this "project" will be enough do some mining...

Assuming you really do need this much power, I recommend keeping the two circuits separate. But actually, I would recommend reconfiguring to split into either:

- 2 x 240V x 15A - This gets to use 12 AWG or even 14 AWG wire, sticking with 2 circuits but changing to 240V lighting fixtures.
- 3 x 120V x 20A - This gets to use 12 AWG wire and keep using 120V lighting fixtures.

Any 15A or 20A circuit gets to use smaller wire and, more importantly, standard switches, timers, etc. - standard residential equipment. When you go over 20A on a single circuit you quickly end up in industrial territory, which means good, solid and **expensive** parts.

Answer (score 5):

HELL NO.

### Neutrals don't have circuit breakers

There are probably a dozen rules but let me pick one: NEC 300.3, which requires neutral current to return in the same cable as the hot current.  If you're tying multiple circuits together, then circuit A's neutral current will partially return on circuit B's neutral or vice versa - with all neutral current choosing paths in proportion to the conductance (1/resistance) of the two parallel neutrals. They won't be equal due to differences in length, connection quality, etc. etc., so that means one leg will carry more than its share of neutral current, and thus be overloaded.

That's if everything is working properly.  If one neutral wire breaks, the other one is carrying 200% of current.

Neutrals don't have circuit breakers, and that works *because* Code requires any given neutral only return current for its partner hot (or hots, in a properly designed MWBC).  Thus the neutral inherits overcurrent protection from the hot breaker.  Once you start playing fast and loose with neutrals, that no longer works.

There are also the rules on paralleling, starting with 110.3(B) requiring parallel equipment on the supply end be UL-listed for paralleling.

Even then, you have a 50/50 chance (higher than that if the electrician was doing their job) that the two circuits are on opposite phases, so ganging their hot wires to power a single load would result in a very loud BANG.

Then there's the fact that *a 120V, 30A load is already uncharacteristically high-current* for a 120V load. Generally above 20A, you switch to 240V for a variety of reasons.  So you're talking about a 120V/60A load and that thing should simply not exist.  That is bonkers. That should be a 240V/30A load.

If it needs to have 120V component loads, like a large RV is 240V/50A but is entirely 120V loads internally, then you take 240V w/neutral and split it out internal to your load.